# Eclipse Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem I can't seem to get around. I've created a project in Eclipse (I recreated it from another project that I thought was corrupted). There are no visible errors in any of the files, including the .xml files. However, the project root [project name] itself has an error (red 'x') and so I can't run it.

On a side note, in the default properties file the line:
target=android-4 is underlined in red with the note that 'android' is not spelled correctly. I have not altered this file since it was generated.

Any clues? Target is 1.6, sdk 4. And I'm new at this :)

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already tried this unsuccessfully, but if not, you might want to try the Android Tools > Fix Project Properties action from the context menu of the project root.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse also thinks android-4 is misspelled in my default.properties, so I doubt that is the cause of your build problem.

Does the Problems view describe any issues?  (Window->Show View->Problems)

You could also try cleaning the project in eclipse.  Project->Clean..

Answer (score 1):

if the error message you get is

```
The project cannot be built until the build path errors are resolved.
```

this might help:

1. Open the Project -> Properties
2. Select Java Build Path -> Libraries
3. Add any new library (to be deleted later) -> OK
4. Wait for the workspace to refresh or force a refresh
5. The error should go away
6. Remove the dummy library

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the spelling error by adding that word to a user dictionary, but a spelling error wouldn't prevent a run.